# how to group a data in python

Tags: python

I have a file with data like:

```
  Entry   Freq.
    2     4.5
    3     3.4
    5     4.9
    8     9.1
    12    11.1
    16    13.1
    18    12.2
    22    11.2
```

now the problem I am trying to solve is: I want to make it a grouped data (with range 10) based on the Entry and want to add up the frequencies falling within the range.
e.g. for above table if I group it then it should be like:

```
    Range   SumFreq.
     0-10    21.9(i.e. 4.5 + 3.4 + 4.9 + 9.1)
     11-20   36.4
```

I reached upto column separation with following code but can't be able to perform range separation thing:
my code is:

```
inp = ("c:/usr/ovisek/desktop/file.txt",'r').read().strip().split('\n')
for line in map(str.split,inp):
    k = int(line[0])
    l = float(line[-1])
```

so far is fine but how could I be able to group the data in 10 range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
fr = {}
inp = open("file.txt",'r').read().strip().split('\n')
for line in map(str.split,inp):
    k = int(line[0])
    l = float(line[-1])
    key = abs(k-1) / 10 * 10

    if fr.has_key(key):
        fr[key] += l
    else:
        fr[key] = l

for k in sorted(fr.keys()):
    sum = fr[k]
    print '%d-%d\t%f' % (k+1 if k else 0, k+10, sum)
```

output:

```
0-10    21.900000
11-20   36.400000
21-30   11.200000
```

Comment: but how can I be able to add up frequencies, I'm getting the index values only.give some idea.

Comment: Use defaultdict instead of checking if the key exists.

Comment: @Ovisek I don't know what you mean, I added the output up there for the sample input you gave. should it do something else ?

Comment: @Amr but I am getting this: 0-10 1.000000
21-30 3.000000
41-50 2.000000
91-100 1.000000
191-200 1.000000
221-230 1.000000
231-240 1.000000.................................these are index values not the frequency add ups.

Comment: are you sure you typed the code correctly? seems to me like you did `fr[key] += 1` instead of `fr[key] += l`

Comment: @Amr ha ha! I was fooled by my variable. thanx for figuring me out.

Comment: what is the reason for this `k-1` business?  I think it would make an entry for 11, 21, 31 etc to go into the wrong bin.

Comment: @wim removing k-1 leads to problems with entries like 10,20..etc. for example, 10 would belong to the range 11-20. The code is working fine this way even with the entries you specified.

Comment: oh right, i see what you're saying.  bins like 0-9, 10-19, 20-29 etc. would work more naturally here.

Comment: I know, just wanted to do it like the OP asked :)

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to [ab]use the fact that integer division will give you the right bins:

```
import collections
bin_size = 10
d = collections.defaultdict(float)
for line in map(str.split,inp):
    k = int(line[0])
    l = float(line[-1])
    d[bin_size * (k // bin_size)] += l
```

Answer (score 0):

How about, just adding to your code there:

```
def group_data(range):
    grouped_data = {}
    inp = ("c:/usr/ovisek/desktop/file.txt",'r').read().strip().split('\n')
    for line in map(str.split,inp):
        k = int(line[0])
        l = float(line[-1])
        range_value = k // range
        if grouped_data.has_key(range_value):
            grouped_data[range_value]['freq'] = groped_data[range_value]['freq'] + l
        else:
            grouped_data[range_value] = {'freq':l, 'value':[str(range_value * range) + ':' + str((range_value + 1) * range )]}
    return grouped_data
```

This should give you a dictionary like:

```
{1 : {'value':'0-10', 'freq':21.9} , .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, tested fine:

```
inp = open("/tmp/input.txt",'r').read().strip().split('\n')
interval = 10
index = 0
resultDict = {}
for line in map(str.split,inp):
        k = int(line[0])
        l = float(line[-1])
        rangeNum = (int)  ((k-1)/10 )
        rangeKeyName = str(rangeNum*10+1)+"-"+str((rangeNum+1)*10)
        if(rangeKeyName in resultDict):
                resultDict[rangeKeyName] += l
        else:
                resultDict[rangeKeyName] = l

print(str(resultDict))
```

Would output:

```
{'21-30': 11.199999999999999, '11-20': 36.399999999999999, '1-10': 21.899999999999999}
```

Comment: This code is not fully working for me. Upto 9th Line It is generating the class range well but not getting the added up frequencies. My output as I got with this code is: {'221-230': 1, '21-30': 3, '191-200': 1, '41-50': 2, '1-10': 1, '231-240': 1, '91-100': 1}

Comment: At SO, we are not supposed to write full code , this should help you as starting point.